# Finding subdirs matching a given name

Tags: java, file, apache-commons

I need to find dirs having a given name (I'll call it "fixedname") under a root dir.
I have the following dir structure:

```
- rootdir
-- someName1
--- fixedName
-- somename2
--- fixedName
```

Under the root dir there are some dirs which name is unknow, and under those dirs there are my target dirs. **The result of my "find" should be: [rootDir/someName1/fixedName, rootDir/someName2/fixedName]**

I tried using [Commons FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html), specifically the method [listfiles](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#listFiles%28java.io.File,%20org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.IOFileFilter,%20org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.IOFileFilter%29), doing the following:

```
final File ROOTDIR = new File("/rootdir");
IOFileFilter nameFilter = new NameFileFilter("fixedName");
Collection<File> files = FileUtils.listFiles(ROOTDIR, TrueFileFilter.TRUE, nameFilter);
```

but it doesn't work, since the subdir walk stops at the level of someName* dirs. **I could write a custom method, but I was wondering whether one can achieve what I need using Commons FileUtils or the Java API** (using some high level function, I mean)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd have just done it manually with the File class, something like:

```
    java.util.List<File> result = new ArrayList<File>();
    final String searchFor = "fixedName";

    for (File child : f.listFiles()) {
        result.addAll(Arrays.asList(
            child.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
                public boolean accept(File parent, String childName) {
                    return childName.equals(searchFor);
                }
            }
        )));
    }
```

Comment: +1 for using the standard API, listfiles() is already in the **File** class, I don't see why he used commons-io in the first place

Comment: this code works, but it isn't recursive as Commons listFiles (my question showed my tree, but I'd like to apply it even to more deep ones), and I was just curious whether I had understood correctly  the commons fileutils api

Comment: Easy enough to turn it into a recursive function though. In fact would clean it up anyway. Using Commons listFiles seems unnecessary for this purpose as you can write it in standard API in a few lines in a way that's more understandable.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't personally used this function but from looking at the [API](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/index.html?org/apache/commons/io/package-summary.html), I think you're interpreting the method arguments incorrectly.

listfiles takes a root directory, a file filter and a directory filter.  The directory filter is for determining which sub-directories to look in, not for finding directories.  You want to look for "fixedName" within All sub-directories.  I think you actually want to call the method like this:

```
final File ROOTDIR = new File("/rootdir");
IOFileFilter nameFilter = new NameFileFilter("fixedName");
Collection<File> files = 
      FileUtils.listFiles(ROOTDIR, nameFilter, TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE);
```

Comment: this was my first attempt, but it doesn't work, as the method doesn't descend under the first level, because it stops when comparing - in the nameFilter - "someName1" with "fixedname", so it doesn't explore the files under someName1

Comment: @cdarwin Looking at this in a little more depth, calling the function the way I specify in my answer does in fact walk the tree correctly(try searching for nested file instead of directory).  The issue is that it searches only for files, not directories.  Internally, apache commons creates effFileFilter=AndFileFilter(yourFilter, NotFileFilter(DirectoryFileFilter)).  I don't see anyway around that using this function.